# Cannot add iOS support for versions previous to 13 in Xcode 11

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, uiwindow

I've already followed [this tutorial](https://www.donnywals.com/add-ios-12-support-to-a-new-xcode-11-project/) in both ways, by implementing the @available directives and by removing code/files, but still a black screen displays. Unless I'm missing something I think I've done both things properly.

This is the current status in the way of removing files/code:

SceneDelegate.swift deleted.

AppDelegate.swift like this:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}



}
```

And finally Info.plist like this:

[image]

What am I missing so the screen still displays black due to the program not supporting versions previous to iOS 13?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your AppDelegate file in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

    } else {
        let rootVC = //Initialize root controller
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guide you step by step.

1. 1st remove **SceneDelegate** file from the project.
2. Add **var window: UIWindow?** to AppDelegate.
3. Remove below func from AppDelegate.

   // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
       // Called when a new scene session is being created.
       // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
       return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
   }

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
       // Called when the user discards a scene session.
       // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
       // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
   }
   ```
4. Remove **Application Scene Manifest** key from *Info.plist* file.
5. `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
       let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
       window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
       window!.rootViewController = navigation window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
       return true
   }`

---

***Extra***

Add below delegate methods in **AppDelegate** file, below ***didFinishLaunchingWithOptions***

```
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
```